# how can we share the same spark context

Tags: java, apache-spark

We are trying to integrate Spark in our web application . So what we did is we integrated spark engine in one of our micro services .
Micro service creates a permanant connection with spark so this will serve all user requests. But problem is we have 3 instances of
same micro service . So each will create a diffrent connection with Spark . How can we avoid this . 
I want a shared connection . Is it possible with current implementation ?

```
            spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("MyApp")
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraHost)
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", cassandraPort)
                .config("spark.scheduler.mode", schedularMode)
                .config("spark.executor.instances",executorInstance)
                .config("spark.executor.cores",executorCores)
                .config("spark.executor.memory",executorMemory)
                .master(master).getOrCreate();
```

Could you please advice a better approach for handling this scenario .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using a standalone cluster.

For distributed applications, you can integrate your microservices with some form of HA technique.

One approach (that I successfully used) is to make these microservices form a cluster such that all requests for spark jobs will be serviced by the member with the active driver (a master, in a sense). Hazelcast, Ignite, JGroups are some of the clustering tools one can use.
This has the additional benefit of allowing you to restart your driver when it dies.

There are also systems that allow the reuse of spark contexts, via protocols such as http (one that comes to mind is spark-job-server). Apache Ignite seems to have a spark component for this purpose too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes we are using spark standalone cluster